# Water simulation not working

Tags: rendering, mesh, fluid-simulation

Using Blender 2.90. I had created a cube as the domain and not changed any of the base settings, and a circle as the water inflow, without changing any settings. I then baked the water domain, yet nothing happens in the solid view when playing the timeline. Does Eevee render affects this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, the fluid simulation expects the emitter's mesh to describe the bounds of a volume. The volume of the space inside the mesh affects how much liquid the object contributes to the simulation.

A circle is a flat object that has a volume of zero because one of its dimensions is zero. Therefore without any special settings it will contribute no liquid to the simulation at all.

The easiest option is to use a solid object as the emitter, such as a cylinder or a cube. So long as the object has enough volume to be detected by at least one of the simulation cells (which will depend on the simulation resolution and the size of the domain) it should then contribute liquid to the simulation.

An alternative option is to try out the "Is Planar" and "Surface Emission" settings, which are in the physics properties of the emitter object.

[image: With the emitter selected, go to the physics properties and under "Flow Source" find the "Is Planar" and "Surface Emission" settings.]

"Surface Emission" essentially makes the simulation pretend that the surface of the mesh has volume itself, which in my experience has been sufficient to make small or completely flat emitter objects produce enough liquid for the simulation to work.

"Is Planar" will not do anything for an entirely flat object because its purpose is to disable the contribution of the volume of the space inside the object, but I mention it for completeness here. If your emitter were not completely flat but was still not an enclosed space then you could set "Is Planar" to ensure that the apparent volume of the object is ignored and only the Surface Emission contributes liquid to the simulation.